# Excessive brightness in Vaio VGN-FE31H with Windows 8

Tags: drivers, hotkeys, sony-vaio, brightness

I have a Vaio VGN-FE31H with Windows 8 32bits.

Right now, I don't have any option to ajust brightness and it's way too bright.

I would like to know which driver I have to install to get the hotkeys working. I went to Sony's offical site (http://www.sony.pt/support/pt/product/VGN-FE31H/updates) and the only available program was Vaio Update. I installed it and it doesn't tell me anything about needing drivers (maybe because the laptop is too old?).

Comment: http://richardfearn.wordpress.com/2007/04/23/making-the-brightness-keys-work-on-a-vaio-vgn-fe31h/ there is a start, trying to get old stuff working on new OSes, is a good reason to stick with working oses

Comment: @Psycogeek I did everything that site says, but despite installed those apps don't seem to work on W8. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this works on Windows' other versions but here it goes:

After installing Windows XP on the VGN-FE31H, the screen brightness keys (Fn-F5 and Fn-F6) no longer work. To make them work again you need to install some of the utilities that ship with the laptop, which are also available in the FE3_Utilities.zip download from the Sony web site.

The three utilities are:

```
Utils Installer 1 SonyUtils DLL
Utils Installer 2 Sony Shared Library (this one needs a reboot)
Utils Installer VAIO Event Service
```

The “VAIO Event Service” needs to be running for the keys to work.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from an ASUS laptop, we had to install AHCI hotkey drivers for my hotkeys to work. you could look at your Device Manager and see if there is anything missing drivers and copy the hardware Ids and google those. The best thing to do is see what is missing from the control panel aspect first unless its OEM. In which case, send it back and explain the issue. There also might be a Keyboard filter driver. ***SOME*** windows 7 drivers will work with 8.

Comment: I tried that but the system tells me that everything is up to date... Thanks anyway!